# Adding raw query to eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am developing an application in `Laravel 5.6` I'm having a simple table with following columns:

```
company_id    project_id    company_role_id    company_specialisation_id
```

And this represents the model `AssociateCompanies`, which has relation of `company`, `project`, `role`, `specialisation` now I am having some query to get the attribute:

```
$companies = AssociateCompany::whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->whereHas('projectOwners', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('slug', $request->slug);
    });
})->groupBy('company_id', 'company_specialisation_id')->with('company', 'role', 'specialisation');
```

I want to collect all unique fields with their counts from two columns `company_id` and `specialisation_id`, but `groupBy` is not giving me proper the results so I am unbale to proceed further:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'conxn.project_associate_company.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `project_associate_company` where exists (select *, (select count(*) from `project_associate_company` where `companies`.`id` = `project_associate_company`.`company_id` and `project_associate_company`.`deleted_at` is null) as `associated_projects_count` from `companies` where `project_associate_company`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` and exists (select * from `projects` inner join `project_owner_relation` on `projects`.`id` = `project_owner_relation`.`project_id` where `companies`.`id` = `project_owner_relation`.`company_id` and `slug` = lodha-patel-estate-tower-a-b-mumbai and `projects`.`deleted_at` is null) and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null) and `project_associate_company`.`deleted_at` is null group by `company_id`, `company_specialisation_id`)"

So I tried running raw queries like this:

```
$companies = AssociateCompany::whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($request) {
        $q->whereHas('projectOwners', function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where('slug', $request->slug);
        });
    })->selectRaw(DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS count GROUP BY company_id , company_specialisation_id'))
    ->with('company', 'companyRole', 'specialisation')->get();
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY company_id , company_specialisation_id from `project_associate_company`' at line 1 (SQL: select COUNT(*) AS count GROUP BY company_id , company_specialisation_id from `project_associate_company` where exists (select *, (select count(*) from `project_associate_company` where `companies`.`id` = `project_associate_company`.`company_id` and `project_associate_company`.`deleted_at` is null) as `associated_projects_count` from `companies` where `project_associate_company`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` and exists (select * from `projects` inner join `project_owner_relation` on `projects`.`id` = `project_owner_relation`.`project_id` where `companies`.`id` = `project_owner_relation`.`company_id` and `slug` = lodha-patel-estate-tower-a-b-mumbai and `projects`.`deleted_at` is null) and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null) and `project_associate_company`.`deleted_at` is null)"

Suggest me better way to get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I want to notice you can not "group by" inside the "select" statement.

So you can not aggregate the non-aggregated columns. This means is grouped fields can be has got multiple "role" so you can not "load" the "roles". The query should be like the one of the follows:

```
AssociateCompany::whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->whereHas('projectOwners', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('slug', $request->slug);
    });
})->select('company_id', 'company_specialisation_id', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))
->groupBy('company_id', 'company_specialisation_id')
->with('company', 'specialisation');
```

Or :

```
AssociateCompany::whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->whereHas('projectOwners', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('slug', $request->slug);
    });
})->select('company_id', 'company_specialisation_id', 'company_role_id', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))
->groupBy('company_id', 'company_specialisation_id', 'company_role_id')
->with('company', 'specialisation', 'role');
```

My suggestions are like this but I think you can solve it with raw MySQL queries rather than use to Eloquent.